# Android Studio: Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='/Users/.../app'

Tags: android

I just updated my project to include the latest version of gradle however now I am receiving this error in yellow.

Gradle 'App' project refresh failed:
           Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='/Users/username/Desktop/App/app'
           Gradle settings

When I click on the log, it takes me to the build.gradle file and moves the cursor to the signingConfigs > release section.

Below are my gradle files. For the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 9
    versionName "2.0"
}

Properties debugProps = new Properties()
debugProps.load(new FileInputStream(project.file("debug.properties")))


Properties releaseProps = new Properties()
releaseProps.load(new FileInputStream(project.file("release.properties")))


signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file(debugProps.KEYSTORE_FILE)
        storePassword debugProps.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias debugProps.KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword debugProps.KEY_PASSWORD
    }

    release {
        storeFile file(releaseProps.KEYSTORE_FILE)
        storePassword releaseProps.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias releaseProps.KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword releaseProps.KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')
}
```

And for the build.gradle that contains the version

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I build the app,the same problem blocked me too. Gradle log said that "Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='XX/XX'". I tackled it.
In my situation ,the bad point located at build.gradle file of the app. The error log told me which line caused the error. I found that line referring a file path parameter, while the parameter is read from a properties file. But the parameter not exist in that properties file!!! That is the source of the problem. So I appended a parameter to the properties file. Problem solved.